# como puedo guardar un checkbox en base de datos

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

sigo buscando solución al problema con el localStorage, sin embargo me comentaron que puedo guardar el state del checkbox en mi base de datos, la cosa es que de esa manera ya investigue, pero no doy con la respuesta, en primera porque no estoy asignando ningún valor al checkbox, únicamente lo utilizare a modo de indicador.

```
function clicked(checkBox){        
    $.ajax({
       url: 'route/saveState.php', //no se que debe contener
       type: "POST",
       data: {state: checkBox.checked},       
       success: function (data) {  
           checkBox.disabled = true;
       },
       error: function (data) { alert(data.responseText); }
}

function getState(){
    $.ajax({
       url: 'route/getState.php', //no se que debe contener
       type: "POST",
       dataType: "json",
       success: function (data) {  
           let error = data.error;
           if(error){
              return;
           }
           let checkBox = document.querySelector("#box");
           checkBox.checked = data.state;
           checkBox.disabled = true;
       },
       error: function (data) { alert(data.responseText); }
}

getState()
```

Comment: Saludos. El `checked` es por defautl (en la interfaz) un valor booleano (`true`o `false`); si esto se te complica pásalo antes de guardar a numero (para que sea `1` o  `0`) o a un caracter (digamos `S` o `N`) según prefieras. Y al obtenerlo verificas `checkBox.checked=(data.state==AquiElNumeroOCaracterQueEsTRUE)`.

Comment: @RobertoLeOr ¿y si en este caso requiero insertar el checked y el disabled ?

Comment: Saludos de nuevo. En tu Reglas de negocio es como debes adaptar tu código para comportamiento del sistema; esto es; (a manera de ejemplo) si al momento que cliquean (ya sea que este marcado y lo desmarquen o viceversa; tu código indica cliquear no se deshabilita por algún estatus) el `checkBox` se debe deshabilitar el `disabled` ya lo tienes. Tus `//no se que debe contener` es ahí tu Reglas de negocio, el flujo del sistema, que procesa para cada caso, valida y recibe el usuario en retroalimentación.